# I don't understand why this query works?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am very new to SQL and I am confused about this: I read that if you have two identical column names in the select, you must put the table name in front of the column name. That's why I don't understand why this query works, there are no identical column names (also not in tables):

```
select 
    item.brand, item.type, item.game_or_console, 
    count(*) as amount
from 
    item
join
    repair on repair.barcode = item.barcode
where 
    brand = 'sony'
group by 
    item.brand, item.type, item.game_or_console
having 
    count (*)  >=1
```

And why this same query but with where instead of join doesn't work:

```
select 
    item.brand, item.type, item.game_or_console, 
    count(*) as amount
from 
    item i, repair r
where 
    r.barcode = i.barcode 
    and brand = 'sony'
group by 
    item.brand, item.type, item.game_or_console
having 
    count (*) >= 1
```

Error:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
> The multi-part identifier "item.brand" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
> The multi-part identifier "item.type" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
> etc.

I tried both queries and only one of them works. But I don't understand why one works and the other not.

Comment: But **DO NOT** start using the second query style! [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: I will try to work with the other one, thank you!

Comment: Just to avoid a misunderstanding: You can still use table aliases (`from item i inner join repair r on r.barcode = i.barcode`). You only have to use that alias then instead of the original table name (`select i.brand, i.type ...`, `group by i.brand, i.type, ...`).

Comment: On a side note: `having count (*)  >=1` has no effect. It tells the DBMS: for every brand/type/game_or_console you find in the table only keep those that you find at least once. But well, everything you find in the table exists at least once in it of course.

Comment: And when working with more than one table, you should always qualifiy *all* columns, i.e. `where item.brand = 'sony'` or `where i.brand = 'sony'`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner yes is that not right? The question for this query was: Give from Sony's consoles per type of console, the number of times it has been submitted for repair. Only show the types that have been offered more than once.

Comment: `having count (*)  >= 1` is "at least once", and you'll get the same result when removing this clause altogether. `having count (*)  > 1` or `having count (*)  >= 2` would be "more than once".

Answer (score 4):

The key point is a table alias:

```
select item.brand, item.type, item.game_or_console, count(*) as amount
from item i, repair r   -- < here
where r.barcode = i.barcode
```

It is no longer possible to access `item` and `repair`  objects as they were renamed to `i` and `r` respectively.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thank you very much!